# Retrieving TextView.getText() to set a CountDownTimer with a Start Button

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer, stringtokenizer

I am in the dawn of my Android programming adventure and have just become able to communicate between on-screen views. So the next step for me is to successfully pull text from a TextView (set by a Dialog) and use a Start Button to run a Timer based on the user selected Dialog (default to the current minute value of the clock).

Here is what you see on [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e99dT.png).

1. A TextView that displays the selection from the Dialog.
2. A Selector Button that launches the Dialog TimePicker Dialog and resets the Start Button.
3. A Start Button that (should) read the TextView, disable itself, and begin a CountDownTimer based on a Long extracted from the TextView string.
4. A debug TextView that displays to me what is actually seen by the system.

The entire activity consists of a single Java File with two Classes declared and of course an XML. Every time I click my start button, despite the Debug TextView showing that I properly extracted the Long value for the seconds the timer instantly completes. I can see from my debug TextView that when I select say.. 08:26, the pSecondsLeft=26 as it should.. but the timer still doesn't count down from 26. I can't see my mistake.

Here is the XML first.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="center"
              android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/timeDisplay"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
              android:text="Time will appear here after being selected"
              android:textSize="30sp"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button android:id="@+id/pickTime"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Change the time"/>

        <Button android:id="@+id/startTimer"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Start the time"
                />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/timeRemaining"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
              android:textSize="30sp"
              android:text="Time Remaining"
              />


</LinearLayout>
```

And here is my Main Activity.

```
package com.stembo.android.botskooltimepickertutorial;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TimePickerActivity extends Activity {
    /** Private members of the class */
    private TextView displayTime;
    private Button pickTime;
    private Button startTimer;
    private TextView timeRemaining;

    private int pMinutesLeft;
    private int pSecondsLeft;
    /** This integer will uniquely define the
     * dialog to be used for displaying time picker.*/
    static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID = 0;

    /** Callback received when the user "picks" a time in the dialog */
    private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener =
            new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int minLeft, int secLeft) {
                    pMinutesLeft = minLeft;
                    pSecondsLeft = secLeft;
                    updateDisplay();
                    displayToast();
                }
            };

    /** Updates the time in the TextView */
    private void updateDisplay() {
        displayTime.setText(
                new StringBuilder()
                        .append(pad(pMinutesLeft)).append(":")
                        .append(pad(pSecondsLeft)));
    }

    /** Displays a notification when the time is updated */
    private void displayToast() {
        Toast.makeText(this, new StringBuilder().append("Time choosen is ")
                .append(displayTime.getText()),   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    /** Add padding to numbers less than ten */
    private static String pad(int c) {
        if (c >= 10)
            return String.valueOf(c);
        else
            return "0" + String.valueOf(c);
    }

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        /** Capture our View elements */
        displayTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeDisplay);
        pickTime = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pickTime);
        startTimer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startTimer);
        timeRemaining = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeRemaining);

        /** Listener for click event of the pick button */
        pickTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startTimer.setEnabled(true);
                showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);
            }
        });

        /**Listener for click event of the start button */
        startTimer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                startTimer.setEnabled(false);
                StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(displayTime.getText().toString(), ":");
                while (st.hasMoreElements()){
                    st.nextElement();
                    long pSecondsTimer = Long.parseLong(st.nextToken());
                }
                timeRemaining.setText(displayTime.getText()+" Token="+ pSecondsLeft);
                long oneSecondInterval = 1000;
                MyCount counter = new MyCount(pSecondsLeft, oneSecondInterval);
                counter.start();
            }
        });

        /** Get the current time */
        final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        pMinutesLeft = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        pSecondsLeft = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        /** Display the current time in the TextView */
        updateDisplay();
    }

    /** Create a new dialog for time picker */

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
            case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
                return new TimePickerDialog(this,
                        mTimeSetListener, pMinutesLeft, pSecondsLeft, true);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer {
        public MyCount(long pSecondsLeft, long countDownInterval){
            super(pSecondsLeft, countDownInterval);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long pSecondsTimer){
            displayTime.setText("Time remaining: " + pSecondsLeft);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish(){
            displayTime.setText("Countdown Complete!");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Start Button code which I am having trouble with, its in the Main Activity but may be easier to see excluded.

```
/**Listener for click event of the start button */
        startTimer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                startTimer.setEnabled(false);
                StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(displayTime.getText().toString(), ":");
                while (st.hasMoreElements()){
                    st.nextElement();
                    long pSecondsTimer = Long.parseLong(st.nextToken());
                }
                timeRemaining.setText(displayTime.getText()+" Token="+ pSecondsLeft);
                long oneSecondInterval = 1000;
                MyCount counter = new MyCount(pSecondsLeft, oneSecondInterval);
                counter.start();
            }
        });
```

Comment: You should note that onCreateDialog is deprecated. Instead, you should use the new DialogFragment with FragmentManager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears there is a misunderstanding about the values you get back from [TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener.html). It gives you hours and minutes, but you're expecting minutes and seconds. Same for the values coming out of the Calendar you're using on onCreate.

That said, if you are *still* trying to use a TimePickerDialog to get minutes and seconds with a full understanding that you're reinterpreting the values, you will need to multiply the number of "seconds" you receive from the picker by 1000 to get a unit in milliseconds that you can feed to the CountDownTimer.

```
MyCount counter = new MyCount(pSecondsLeft * 1000, oneSecondInterval);
```

Comment: Yes it does give hours and minutes, so I realize that by re-interpreting them I limit myself to a timer of 24 minutes and 59 seconds based on my implementation, but I was just using it as a small step to communicate between things I understand at the moment. Once I have this down my next step will be to replace the timer with some dialog (or whatever) that can go up to 99, or 999 etc.

I guess I left some things out of my translation, I'll go re-evaluate based on your input and report back, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you're not subtracting from the pSecondsLeft variable on each tick

```
public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer {
        public MyCount(long pSecondsLeft, long countDownInterval){
            super(pSecondsLeft, countDownInterval);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long pSecondsTimer){
            displayTime.setText("Time remaining: " + pSecondsLeft);
            pSecondsLeft --;           
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish(){
            displayTime.setText("Countdown Complete!");
        }
    }
```